# Cannot install gems with SocketError

Tags: rubygems

I cannot install any gems because of this error:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
    getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
$ gem sources --list
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

I am using gem behind a proxy, and I have already set http_proxy and https_proxy environment. I can connect to any websites in my shell.

```
$ wget https://rubygems.org
```

The version of my gem is:

```
$ gem -v
2.2.2
```

I have search a lot of solutions, but none of them can solve my problem. Anyone can provide some suggestions? Thank you.

UPDATE

I also tried:

```
$ gem install rails --http-proxy http://host:port
```

but failed.

Comment: Did you find a way how to solve the problem?

Comment: No, I don't know where goes wrong. I guess it's because of my proxy.

Comment: Well. I spend several hours to find the solution. But finally just downloaded gem from rubygems and installed it from local source.

Comment: After seeking a number of solutions, I still cannot fix it. So, I thought that could be my problem and gave up installing gems behind proxy.